# How to launch a shortcut when installation completes

Tags: wix

I have a WIX project that is creating an MSI to install an Excel VSTO application, including desktop shortcuts to launch the application.   The installation and shortcut creation is working fine.   But I need to be able to launch the application by executing the shortcut after the installation has completed.   I've seen guides on how to launch an executable, but nothing for a shortcut.  Is there some way of doing this that I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How is launching shortcut different from launching the executable? I mean the shortcut points to an executable plus maybe some command line arguments. The result is a running application anyway, then why bothering?